# Trouble with the choose.files()-function in R

Tags: r, filechooser

I want to open several files with R and therefore use the function choose.files(), which is frequently recommended here in stackoverflow for this purpose. Anyway, this does not work in my code, and I would be very happy if someone can tell me what`s wrong.
This is the beginning of my code:

```
corpus1<-scan(choose.files(default="C:/Desktop/test", caption = "Select 
files", multi = TRUE))
```

... and this is the output:

```
Error in file(file, "r") : invalid 'description' argument
In addition: Warning message:
In if (file == "") file <- stdin() else { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

Thanks in advance!
M_Be

Comment: choose.files is for finding files interactively, which is not the way that you are using it. By interactively, I mean that you call the function choose.files() and it will open up a prompt for your to find the file that you want to open. Run choose.files() by itself and you will see what I mean.

Comment: So it is not possible to open more than one file with it?

Comment: ...and this was interactively, as a prompt opened and I chose 3 files and then this error message came up

Comment: you can open them one at a time, but not all at once. You can never open more than 1 file at a time in R. If you want to open multiple files programatically, you can use a for loop or apply function.

Comment: Thank you! I guess i was just confused by the word fileS, which suggerates to me that it is possible to open multiple files at the same time.